# Convertir de Fecha y Hora solo Hora y Minutos en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenos días tengo este query

```
convert(char(8), Horario.HoraInicio, 108)
```

pero cuando le doy `run` me sale `00:00:00` pero yo solo quiero que me de `00:00`

alguna idea,

Gracias

Comment: y si cambios char(8) por char(5)?

Comment: Pues si tienes razón eh estado tan concentrado en algo que perdí la noción de la realidad gracias por recalcarlo (Y)

Comment: @gbianchi es mejor colocarlo como respuesta; así el OP puede considerar aceptar su respuesta.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave ni siquiera es una respuesta, no sabria ni que poner ni porque...

Answer (score 1):

Con la función `TIME_FORMAT` especificas lo que quieras por ejemplo horas , minutos y segundos `'%H:%i:%s'` en tu caso solo necesitas horas y minutos por eso se usa `'%H:%i'`. Con la función `time` obtienes la hora de cualquier date-time.

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(TIME('2018-01-01 22:52:59'),'%H:%i');
```

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta que tu solución es para MySql, el OP puntualmente esta consultando por SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se hace así en TSQL:

```
convert(char(5), GETDATE(), 108)
```

Puedes mirar acá:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017